# Hiding specific variables in workspace after function calculations in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm using *GUI* in ***Matlab*** to create some matrices. I have a panel with 4 checkboxes functions like this:

```
function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

let's say that every *checkbox* compute those matrices *height, mass, density and power*. When i check each one individually, it correctly evaluates the  requested matrix, ***but*** i have to check them in the order they are because the results of each depend on the previous ones. I have result this problem by just adding the code of the previous ones in every function. When i calculate the density, the *workspace window* has as variables the density and also the height and mass. I want in the function of density to use a command that after the calculations, it will appear in the *workspace* only the density matrix. I used the following two

```
clearvars ('-except', 'density')

clear height mass
```

but it appears that when i run it, it doesn't work cause it keeps all the variables in the *workspace* , **but** not error is appearing. When i run it in the *command window* it works but i want to make it work inside the function. How can i achieve that?

Comment: It is not clear how your GUI works. It sounds like there are things computed and written to the base workspace when you select a check box? That sounds counter-intuitive. Why not an "OK" button that computes and writes the right values, depending on the settings of the check boxes at that time? That would make your logic simpler as well.

Comment: Just one question: is the result of the first calculation (produced by clicking the first checkbox) necessary to perform the second calculation?  And is, similarly, the second result necessary in order to obtain the third one?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo yes, to calculate the second, i need the results of the first and to calculate the third i need the results of the first and the second. I edit my question, i hope is more clear now.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i edit my question. I hope now it's more clear what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what concerns your `clearvars` issue, that's because the function, by design, performs the requested cleanup only within the scope in which it's being called. Althrough it's not a good idea to mess around with workspace variables (you have better alternatives, like storing your data in `GUI` handles and clear those when it's done)... here is a snippet, based on your example, that shows you how to achieve your goal:

```
function myFunction()
    % perform some calcunations...
    evalin('base','clearvars(''-except'',''density'')');
end
```

The [evalin](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html) functions allows to evaluate a specific expression (in this case, a `clearvars` call) within a specific workspace (in this case, the base Matlab workspace). But I recommend you to tweak it **veeeeery carefully**, otherwise the risk is to dispose other very important variables (I'm signally thinking about the ones managing the current `GUI` data and handlers).

For what concerns your current `GUI` design, I recommend you to rethink it completely. First of all, you should never change the behavior of a common and well known control: I don't expect a 10 minutes long calculation to start when I click on a checkbox; I expect it when I press a button. On the top of that, checkboxes are good for expressing indepentent choices, not sequential ones... so use a dropdown combobox instead:

```
Which variable do you want to calculate?
   > Height
   > Mass
   > Density
   > Power
```

Users pick one of the values in the dropdown window, and then they press a button in order to start the computation. The calculation will be then performed in a single shot, and your code will know when to stop by checking the combobox value.

Comment: it works, i didn't think to insert the clearvars inside evalin. Thanks!